# How To Set global current_user on Wordpress Using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am using the following code to login a user.

`$UserName` and `$Password` is coming in via a Form. The following if statement is showing TRUE, so my user is getting logged in.

```
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $UserName );
if ( $user && wp_check_password( $Password, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) )
```

Now as long as the User is on the website I want his `$UserName` to be known by all the PHP programs he invokes.

Whenever I log someone in using the wp-admin screen the `$UserName` is brought in to all PHP programs by executing the following code:

```php
global $current_user;
if ( isset($current_user) ) {
    $UserName=$current_user->user_login;
}
```

My question is.... using the login at the top of this post how do I save the $Username in such a way that it is brought into other PHP programs using the above `isset($current_user)` if statement?

I tried the following code but it does not bring the `$current_user` field into other PHP programs by executing the `IF (isset($current_user)` statement. The `$user->user_login` field contents is equal to `$UserName`.:

```php
$user_id = $UserName;
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
$current_user=  new WP_User( $user_id , $user->user_login );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
global $current_user;
```

What am I missing?  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If `$current_user` is in the global namespace (not in a function or a class), then you need to use `global $current_user;` in all functions/methods you want to use it in. Defining it as `global` doesn't automatically make it available everywhere. Another solution could be to set the user as a constant instead of a variable, which are accessible everywhere by design.

Comment: global $current_user is being used in all php programs that check to see if the person is logged in. How do you set the field up as a constant?  Is it possible the "isset" in the IF statement is the cause of the problem ?

Comment: No, the `isset()` only checks if the variable is defined and not null, so if it set, it would just evaluate as true. Why don't you use WP's own [wp_get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) instead? It's also hard to know exactly what's going on since we don't know the context of this code or when you set what where. Is all the code within the same request, or are you expecting `$current_user` to be accessible between request? If yes, then you need to store it in a session. But use WP's own function instead

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this code   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( $current_user->exists() ) {
       $UserName=$current_user;
    }     The if ($current_user->exists()) was not true.

Comment: How do i store $current_user in a session?

Comment: It is during multiple request... user brings up the Login Screen, The return is a form, The submit button is clicked on the form, then in the next php program I check to see if the user is logged in.

Comment: Storing it as a SESSION does not work because once the user goes to another page the SESSON information is gone.

Comment: Sessions is for the opposite (keeping data between requests) so if it doesn't work, then there must be something you're missing in your implementation. A common issue is that people forget to call `session_start()` before trying to read from or write to the session variables. You also need to start the session before you output anything at all (including any HTML, echo's or even a space before the opening `<?php`.)